# Facebook SDK Login in android

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-activity

i'm trying to use a Facebook login in my app, in my fragment activity i've got 4 tabs and i want to display and use Facebook login in the last tab, but when i run it it shows me Facebook login button in every tabs and it doesn't work when i click on it, also app closes in 1 minute

this is the simpleFragement activity code:

```
package com.tekinarslan.material.sample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

import static com.tekinarslan.material.sample.R.layout.page;

public class SampleFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";
    private WebView myWebView;
    private String LOG_TAG = "AndroidWebViewActivity";

    private int position;

    public static SampleFragment newInstance(int position) {
        SampleFragment f = new SampleFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(page, container, false);

        ProgressBarCircular progressBarCircular = (ProgressBarCircular) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabButton);
        WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        fab.setDrawableIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.plus));




            switch (position) {
            case 0:


                webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");



                break;
            case 1:

                webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

                break;
            case 2:

                webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

                break;
            case 3:

                LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
                loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
                // If using in a fragment
                loginButton.setFragment(this);
                // Other app specific specialization

                // Callback registration
                CallbackManager callbackManager = null;
                loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                    }
                });
                break;
                    }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**UP**

**EDIT1**

This is my hosting activity

```
package com.tekinarslan.material.sample;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;


public class SampleActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    private ListView mDrawerList;
    ViewPager pager;
    private String titles[] = new String[]{"Sample Tab 1", "Sample Tab 2", "Sample Tab 3", "Sample Tab 4"};
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navdrawer);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_ab_drawer);
        }
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        pager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), titles));

        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(pager);
        slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return Color.WHITE;
            }
        });
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        String[] values = new String[]{
                "DEFAULT", "RED", "BLUE", "MATERIAL GREY"
        };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        mDrawerList.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_deep_teal_500));
                        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_deep_teal_500));
                        slidingTabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_deep_teal_500));
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mDrawerList.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                        slidingTabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mDrawerList.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                        slidingTabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);

                        break;
                    case 3:
                        mDrawerList.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_blue_grey_800));
                        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_blue_grey_800));
                        slidingTabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_blue_grey_800));
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);

                        break;
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

**EDIT2**

i added this two lines

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
```

But the app, closes when i click on Facebook button or slide the tabs

**EDIT 3**

Now here is the logcat:
`05-02 19:18:54.784  24164-24164/com.tekinarslan.material.sample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Log in attempt failed: LoginActivity could not be started
            at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.startLogin(LoginManager.java:382)
            at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(LoginManager.java:250)
            at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$LoginClickListener.onClick(LoginButton.java:689)
            at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase$1.onClick(FacebookButtonBase.java:310)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method`

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you initialize the SDK in the hosting activity using this line:

```
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Also initialize the callBackManager like so:

```
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

**EDIT 1**

Register the `LoginActivity` in the `AndroidManifest` file.

After you've registered a callback you should forward the login results to the `callbackManager` by overriding `onActivityResult()` like so:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: added it, but still not works, see my edits please @MohamedSaad

Comment: ok now put these two lines before setContentView() method @Jack_usti

Comment: what is the crash message in logcat? @Jack_usti

Comment: No need to upload it all but if there's no crash then you are good to go! while if the app closes without crash then check your code logic. And you can check the docs here for fragments:
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3 @Jack_usti

Comment: in `SampleFragment` class make sure you initialize the `callBackManager` like u did in the hosting activity @Jack_usti

Comment: yes, i did it but not works.. i want that fb login button is displayed only in a view (for ex. case 4) @MohamedSaad

Comment: Have you registered the `LoginActivity` in the manifest file? and also override the `onActivityResult()` method in your activity. see EDIT 1 @Jack_usti